# The Operation Could not be completed. Invalid Pointer - VS2010 SP1

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008-sp1

I am working on an asp.net project in web forms. When i working on the project yesterday power went out and the system went to improper shutdown.

After that today i tried to open my solution, the .cs file is not opening. VS shows error as

> *The Operation Could not be completed. Invalid Pointer*

And the .cs file was opened on notepad as empty. I am not sure what is the issue.

Could any one help me to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might have a look at my answer regarding to this problem on **[Visual Studio Hosting Process and “The operation could not be completed”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33338/visual-studio-hosting-process-and-the-operation-could-not-be-completed/50497064#50497064)**.

Answer (score 11):

Resolved this problem by clearing this folder:

```
c:\Users\<myusername>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache
```

Comment: I could open .cs files but not .cshtml files. However, this worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Check those links:
http://qualapps.blogspot.com.es/2010/07/invalid-pointer-error-in-visual-studio.html

[The Operation could not be completed: Invalid Pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252927/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-invalid-pointer)

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error and I have tried the following with NO SUCCES

- Rename `%ProgramFiles%\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\VS7DEBUG` to something else. I changed it to `VS7DEBUG1`.
- Delete the content of `%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache`
- Installed [Servicing Update (KB3110221)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/01/26/servicing-update-available-for-visual-studio-update-1/)
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetuserdata`
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe /resetsettings`

**I finally uninstalled visual studio 2015. Restarted and installed it again and then it worked.**

Answer (score 0):

Please clear this folder:
**%LocalAppData%\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache**