# SQLite not listed in Data Sources window

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, visual-studio-2017

VS2015 Community is not showing SQLite in the list of available data sources in one place and showing it in the other.

- If I click **New Connection** button in **Server Explorer** and click **Change**, I get the following list of Data Sources:

[image]

- If I add a new item to my project > choose Entity Model > from existing database > New Connection, I get the following list of Data Sources:

[image]

How can I get SQLite in the New Connection data sources list?

### Background

The problem started when my existing EDMX failed to load with the infamous error message

> The Operation could not be completed: Invalid Pointer

This error can be fixed by deleting `ComponentModelCache` folder as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252927/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-invalid-pointer). This method has worked for me in the past, but not this time. I finally decided to recreate the EDMX from scratch. Since then I'm facing this issue.

A few things that might give some hint:

- I have recently installed VS2017 Community side-by-side with VS2015. VS2017 can open the existing EDMX just fine, but cannot do **Update from Database**, so I came back to VS2015.
- I uninstalled and reinstalled System.Data.SQLite provider several times, thinking that this might be a registration issue. Didn't do any good.

Note that VS2017 support is not there yet on System.Data.SQLite's [download page](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki). I'm using the last available version that supports VS2015 (version number 1.0.104.0).

Comment: I have some tips here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2014/11/using-sqlite-with-entity-framework-6.html (also check the blog post comments for tips)

Comment: @ErikEJ: Thanks for the input. Good uncle Google had driven me to your blog while I was researching the problem. Good news is that my problem is fixed now; at least for VS2015. Looks like I needed to remove all SQLite packages plus EF package itself and then add them again.

Answer (score 2):

Good news is that the issue is fixed finally; at least for VS2015. Bad news is that I don't know what exactly did the trick. So I'll list down everything that I tried and maybe this could help someone in the future. These steps are not in any particular order.

1. Uninstall all SQLite packages from NuGet.
2. Uninstall Entity Framework package too.
3. Reinstall all these packages.
4. Remove and reinstall the [latest version of SQLite provider](https://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) (1.0.104.0 as of this writing).
5. Use VS2015 only. VS2017 is currently not supported by SQLite provider.
6. [Clear ComponentModelCache folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14252927/the-operation-could-not-be-completed-invalid-pointer) and restart Visual Studio.

Comment: **Even if you're on a 64-bit machine, you need to download the 32-bit version.**

Answer (score 0):

I found an easy solution, just install below extension from market place and Sqlite will be available to data source list

[SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ErikEJ.SQLServerCompactSQLiteToolbox)